# Automating appending numbers to the end of paragraphs, numbered paragraphs

Tags: epub, conversion, creation

I'm formatting an ebook that uses line numbers. The only problem is the numbers have not been provided, so I would have to enter them all myself.

How can I add these line numbers, maybe using PERL (I have a very cursory knowledge of it myself). I think I basically need to append a number to the end of each paragraph, incrementing by 1.

Comment: I cleaned up your question, assuming you don't want to know if *someone* knows how to do what you want (which is a yes/no answerable question). The main problem is that your question is still ambiguous as you write about **line numbers** (hard as a line depends on device/font settings etc) and give an example of having paragraphs numbered (actually relatively easy), what is it you want?

Comment: In addition to Anthon's question, what file format are the documents you're working with? MS Word documents, HTML, an XML format, PDF, InDesign?